# Javadoc: Add @throws from nested method calls

Tags: java, javadoc

Guess this methods:

```
/**
* Description
* @throws EspaiDocFault
*/
public void doSomething() {
   throw new EspaiDocFault();
}

/**
* Description
*/
public void doAnotherThing() {
    this.doSomething();
}
```

where `EspaiDocFault` is:

```
public class EspaiDocFault extends RuntimeException {}
```

Should I add `@throws EspaiDocFault` in `doAnotherThing` java-doc?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16757066/javadoc-and-runtimeexception